# Property not working in ngModel (Angular 2), error

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

I'm trying to create a form using Angular 2, but I am with the following error:

> core.umd.js:3370 EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'ProductName' of undefinedErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3370next @ core.umd.js:6838schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6088SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6080onError @ core.umd.js:6303onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6179ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js:139drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
>       core.umd.js:3375 ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3375next @ core.umd.js:6838schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6088SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6080onError @ core.umd.js:6303onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6179ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js:139drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
>       core.umd.js:3376 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProductName' of undefined
>           at AppView._View_ProductAddComponent0.detectChangesInternal (ProductAddComponent.ngfactory.js:542)
>           at AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9470)
>           at AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:9496)
>           at AppView.detectChangesInternal (core.umd.js:9481)
>           at AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9470)
>           at AppView.detectContentChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:9488)
>           at AppView._View_AppComponent0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent.ngfactory.js:469)
>           at AppView.detectChanges (core.umd.js:9470)
>           at AppView.detectViewChildrenChanges (core.umd.js:9496)
>           at AppView._View_AppComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (AppComponent_Host.ngfactory.js:86)ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.umd.js:3376next @ core.umd.js:6838schedulerFn @ core.umd.js:6088SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.ts:238SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:190Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.ts:135Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.ts:95Subject.next @ Subject.ts:61EventEmitter.emit @ core.umd.js:6080onError @ core.umd.js:6303onHandleError @ core.umd.js:6179ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:207Zone.runTask @ zone.js:139drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:368ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:308
>       zone.js:357 TypeError: Cannot read property 'ProductName' of undefined(…)

I tried to follow the Angular 2 Getting Start Tutorial, changing the variables and objects for what I need. But the error continues happening.
What am I doing wrong?
Here is my code.

My model:

```
export class Product {
    constructor(
        public ProductName: string,
        public ProductDescription: string) { }
}
```

My component:

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model'

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'templates/Product_Add.html'
})

export class ProductAddComponent {

    public title: string = "Add Product"
    public product: Product;

    product_register(){
    }
}
```

My template:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{ title }}</h3>
    </div>
    <form #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="product_register(form.value)">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="1" maxlength="40" [(ngModel)]="product.ProductName"/>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-12">
                    <label>Description</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="2" maxlength="200" [(ngModel)]="product.ProductDescription"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Save</a>&nbsp;
            <a class="btn btn-default" type="reset">Reset</a>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

---

I try change my model to:

```
export interface Product {
    ProductName: string;
    ProductDescription;
}
```

and to:

```
export class Product {
    public ProductName: string;
    public ProductDescription: string;
}
```

But the same error appears,
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { Product } from '../models/product.model'

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'templates/Product_Add.html'
})

export class ProductAddComponent {

    public title: string = "Add Product"

    private product:Product = new Product();
    //public product: Product;

    product_register(){
    }
}
```

change the class to

```
export class Product {
    public ProductName: string;
    public ProductDescription: string;

    constructor(){}
}
```

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/forms#create-the-hero-model-class says define the attribute inside constructor and it gives errors of "not able to read property of undefined".. in console I don't know what's wrong!